# Deserializing json in c# returns null

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

This is my JSON string:

```
"{\"1\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"},\"2\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"},\"7\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"},\"8\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"},\"9\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"},\"10\":{\"Name\":\"macintosh\",\"ShortDescription\":\"red\",\"LongDescription\":\"dfhdfh\"}}"
```

This is the JSON object:

```
{
    "1": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    },
    "7": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    },
    "8": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    },
    "9": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    },
    "10": {
        "Name": "macintosh",
        "ShortDescription": "red",
        "LongDescription": "dfhdfh"
    }
}
```

And here are my classes:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Friends
{
    public Dictionary<int, MyModel> data { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I try to deserialize it:

```
Friends facebookFriends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Friends>(theJsonString);
```

but then `facebookFriends.data` gives me `null` value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var friends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, MyModel>>(theJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues. The deserialiser expects to see a `data` object, which you don't have in the JSON string. Also, the "keys" you have are strings, not integers. So you want something like this:

```
Friends facebookFriends = new Friends();
facebookFriends.data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, MyModel>>(theJsonString);
```

You also need to update your model of course:

```
public class Friends
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyModel> data { get; set; }
}
```